# xcopy batch file pst backup

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to build a batch file script, which will copy the outlook.pst file, from the user's My Documents folder and move it to the server, which I've mapped as a drive, "B:\"

This is the code I have so far:

```
@echo on
xcopy "c:\Documents and Settings\%username%\My Documents\outlook.pst" "B:\PST\%username%\" -c -d -i -y
exit
```

The script is designed for Windows XP.

However, when I run this code on the client machine, it doesn't copy the .pst file across, it just runs the command over and over again, until I Ctrl + C it...

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using `xcopy` rather than `copy`?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the default location for PST files is in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\`.  And if the user has PST files in multiple locations, it's possible that he has more than one with the same name, just in different folders.  Good times.

If it's possible that your users might have PST files in locations other than `My Documents`, I recommend modifying your script with just a couple of very minor changes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%userprofile%" %%I in (*.pst) do (

    rem avoid overwriting in case "outlook.pst" exists in two locations, for instance
    if exist "B:\PST\%username%\%%~nxI" (
        set cnt=000

        rem get count of files matching b:\pst\username\filename*.pst
        for /f %%a in ('dir "B:\PST\%username%\%%~nI*%%~xI" 2^>NUL ^| find " File(s) "') do (
            set "cnt=!cnt!%%a"
        )

        rem file of the same name will become filename001.pst, filename002.pst, etc.
        set "dest=%%~nI!cnt:~-3!%%~xI"

    rem otherwise leave the filename alone
    ) else set "dest=%%~nxI"
    set /P "=Copying !dest!... "<NUL
    copy "%%~fI" "B:\PST\%username%\!dest!"
    echo Done.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wished to copy outlook.pst from its Microsoft default location to a memory stick using a batch file in Windows XP
I found that xcopy failed to copy Outlook.pst to the memory stick or to My Documents

I now xcopy it in 2 steps, firstly to C:\ then to the Memory Stick

It has worked reliably